# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { using JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm working on a web interface for a DYI project. I have limited coding skills as i am on the learning process.

This is part of my code:

```
var lights_array = [22,23,24,25,26];
function pull_light_status (lights_array){
    var devices = {};
    devices.veraip = "10.20.174.10";
    create_device_array (devices, lights_array);        
    $.post( "resources/php/individual_json.php", devices)
        .done(function (json) {
        var vera_obj = JSON.parse(json);
        console.log(vera_obj);

    }); 
}

function create_device_array (devices, ligh_arr){
    $.each(ligh_arr,function(key,value){
        eval("devices.device_"+key+"="+ value);           
    });          
}

pull_light_status(lights_array);
```

What im trying to do is to generate a post to the invidiviual_json.php so it will process the json request for all the devices and then send me an response i can use in js.

This is the content of individual_json.php

```
<?php
$veraip = $_POST['veraip'];
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
switch ($key){
case "veraip":
    break;
default: 
    echo damejson ($veraip,$value);
    break;
}
}
function damejson ($ip,$device){
$url = 'http://' . $ip . '/port_3480/data_request?id=status&DeviceNum=' . $device;
$jsondata_ind = file_get_contents($url);
return $jsondata_ind;
}
?>
```

Whenever i add the line `var vera_obj = JSON.parse(json);` i get an error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Can someone explain me what am i doing wrong and maybe what can i do to fix it?
What i would like is to have a js object in vera_obj i can work with

Thanks in advance

J

EDIT --------------
Changed it to this, i got nothing in console

```
    function pull_light_status (lights_array){
    var devices = {};
    devices.veraip = "10.20.174.10";
    create_device_array (devices, lights_array);        
    $.getJSON( "resources/php/individual_json.php", {device:devices})
        .done(function (vera_obj) {
        console.log(vera_obj);
        console.log(typeof(vera_obj));

    }); 
}

function create_device_array (devices, ligh_arr){
    $.each(ligh_arr,function(key,value){
        eval("devices.device_"+key+"="+ value);           
    });          
}
```

Comment: Have you actually tried the `getJSON` method? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: i have not, i will try tho, just need check how to change it to use getJSON.  Ill post back once i figure it out and try it

Comment: Having been able to get it work either.  With the current scenario, does anyone has some ideas on how get an object of the return string?

Comment: `getJSON` should give you a JSON object if the returned string is valid JSON.

Comment: Oh and you need to tell jQuery the Content-Type is json, by sending the appropriate header with php `header("Content-Type: application/json");`

Comment: Apologies as im pretty new to javascript, maybe too new to be doing this, but ill keep trying.  Mind to check the edit code above and tell me what i need to change?  if its not much to ask

Comment: Also check the browser's console for errors after executing your code.

Comment: You need to send said `header()` command before you return the value `return $jsondata_ind;`.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  I dont get you, maybe im too new for this.  i dont even know if the code above is right or not.  Anyways, thanks again, ill keep looking